# Searching forward through bash history

Tags: bash

You can hit ctrl-r from the command line to initiate a search for a previously issued command. You can then hit ctrl-r to cycle back through the older commands that match the search string.

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to cycle forward through the commands after you've cycled backwards. ctrl-s is supposed to do this but it doesn't work for me. I've search google but have come up empty on finding an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may like [Rob's Terminal History Management](https://www.macworld.com/article/1146015/os-x/termhistory.html). You get matches, then the up and down arrow keys let you browse. Almost forgot, the file you want to edit is now ".bash_profile". Open your home folder and press <kbd>⇧⌘.</kbd> to see it.

Comment: I tried going into "verbatim mode" like the tutorial said but when I did, the up arrow just moved my cursor up. It didn't insert any special character.

Comment: Position your cursor again, then hold the escape key a little longer before pressing "v". I discovered that the first time I pressed escape+v, it just typed a "v". If that happens you can press delete to get rid if the "v", then try again. If you mess up, you can press ctrl+x, then "n", then try "nano .bash_profile" at the command prompt again.

Comment: It does type a bracket but then when I try to hit the up arrow, it just moves up. There is no "verbatim mode" indicator that pops up as explained in the tutorial.

Comment: OK, I'm starting to wonder about keyboard layout customization for the system or for the Terminal. Do you have a Touch Bar laptop by any chance? I don't have much experience with those, but when editing in Nano in the Terminal, you should be able to see "[ Verbatim Input ]" in reverse contrast just above and at the center of the bottom array of shortcut reminders in the Terminal window. Do you have an alternate keyboard profile selected in Terminal Preferences?

Comment: I have a touch bar, yes.

Comment: Maybe you could temporarily map caps lock to escape as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127591/using-caps-lock-as-esc-in-mac-os-x/40254864#40254864).

Comment: Good thinking but didn't work. Nano's help file says "M-V" is the keystroke to go into verbatim mode which is option-V. That didn't do it either, though.

Comment: We may need to open a chat for this, but one more thing would be to get your input menu into the menu bar by using keyboard prefpane>keyboard tab>show keyboard and emoji viewers... That should make it easy to open the keyboard viewer and see what is being typed in Terminal and not. You may be able to find out what's going on in Terminal preferences for Keyboard. You might try reverting the Encodings to default in that area.

Comment: I stumbled on a great tip which addresses this problem and has the proper syntax for the bash_profile commands. See the last tip on this page: https://mhoffman.github.io/2015/05/21/how-to-navigate-directories-with-the-shell.html. Thanks for your help.